# post only in ascii

Tags: support

I have a plain ascii text that I would like to post by simple copy paste in math SE but my ascii text is interpreted differently. I would like to be able to ask my question in simple ascii, how shall I do it ?

Comment: You're probably using symbols from Markup and MathJax.

Comment: Although it was intended for preparation of long posts requiring elaborate MathJax/$\LaTeX$ markup, you might be interested in trying out your post in the [sandbox thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts).

Comment: ASCII is a character mapping - I think you mean raw text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you indent the text with 4 spaces it will be presented verbatim:

```
This is rendered as is $x$ &ndash; nothing renders.
```

If you have many lines, it could be a pain to indent each. Thus, at first do not indent them. Then highlight the entire block and press the button {}, or press Crtl-K.

Or use `<pre>` and  `</pre>` at the beginning and end, respectively.

For shorter sequences that you do not want to be rendered, you can include them in backticks.